# how to disable future date values in datepicker?

Tags: php, html

I have a date picker but it is enabled for all day to pick. I want to enable the today date and less than today. Future date will be disabled. Are there any plugins available?

Comment: You need to verify it on your server too when processing the request, but you can set the `max` attribute in your input.

Comment: What date picker are you using?  Is it a library or is it just normal html input.  Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

**for HTML5**

`max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"` this will help you dynamically in php.

For illustration purpose, I kept he today's date as per IST.

```html
<input type="date" name="date" max="2018-11-23">
```